# Separate tokens in batch delims with comma but has spaces the string

Tags: batch-file

sorry but I can't resolve this problem. I have in my WinReg this string:

> shell    REG_SZ    cscript C:\shell.vbs C:\start.bat, cscript
>   C:\shell.vbs C:\start2.bat, cscript C:\shell.vbs C:\start3.bat

I'm going to create other "start.bat" (start.bat is an example) but I must shure if exists in the shell, what I did is this:

```
set llave="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
set campo=Shell
set existe=0

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query %llave%  /V %campo%  ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') do set datos=%%a

:SigDato
if "%datos%" == "" goto CreaShell

for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%datos%") do (
    if "%%a"=="C:\path\start4.bat" (
        set existe=1
    ) else (
        if "%existe%"=="1" (
            set existe=1
        ) else (
            set existe=0
        )
    )
    set "datos=%%b"
)

goto SigDato

:CreaShell
if "%existe%"=="0" (
    echo entro
    reg add %llave% /v %campo% /t REG_SZ /d %shellReg%,C:\path\start4.bat /f
)
```

It was working fine in test because I don't have the spaces

> "cscript C:\script.vbs C:\start.bat"

but when I saw that it use spaces, until now I don't know how to take all the string with spaces delims with comma. Can somebody help me?

I appreciate it so much

Comment: Don't call batchfiles `start`. It conflicts with CMD's internal command called `start`.

Comment: Don't use `"tokens=3"`but `"tokens=2*"` that will get all data into %%b (as you did in the 2nd for)